# PHP mysql Xampp failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have this two files:

dbconfig.php

```
 <?php
 class database{
function __construct()
{
    $db_user="root";
    $db_pass="";
    try {
        $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hrm', $db_user, $db_pass);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
       }
      catch(PDOException $e)
      {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
<?php

session_start();

 class user
  {

 private $db;

 function __construct(){

    require_once "../dbconfig.php";
     $this->db= new database();
  }
```

errors:

Warning: require_once(../dbconfig.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\hrm2\Class\class.user.php on line 12

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../dbconfig.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\hrm2\Class\class.user.php on line 12

Path's:
I have dbconfig on htdocs folder and i have the class.user.php file in Class folder. 
Actually i don't know how can the path be wrong because phpstorm is saying that it's right because of the recommended.

[image]

Comment: Make sure the path is correct... PHP is telling you the path isnt correct so you should fix that.

Comment: The thing is that the path is correct, which is really strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using relative paths will get you into trouble. Try using an absolute path with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, then dictate where the file is.

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/dbconfig.php";
```

If it's outside of the document root, then use this to get one level up from the document root.

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../dbconfig.php";
```

Also make sure that the file has read permissions for your webserver's user.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: require(database/db.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\php project\resigistion form\insert.php on line 2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).